# Retrofit Multipart Nested Object

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, multipart

```
[
    {
      “id”: "string",
      "images": [
        null
      ],
      "quantity": 0,
      “description": "string"
    },

    {
      “id”: "string",
      "images": [
        null
      ],
      "quantity": 0,
      “description": "string"
    }
]
```

How can we send the object (like above) using Multipart request in Retrofit. Thank you in advance. i.e an array of objects having images list in it.

Comment: this is just a JSONArray.

Comment: Yes this is a JSON Array but problem is, need to send the images as well, as a part of Multipart data

Comment: you want post request for send ? means retrofit calls ?

Comment: Ashish yes i want to post the multipart request using Retrofit

Comment: Please have a look at second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973677/nested-multipart-request-using-retrofit). Its a similar question.